# ¿Cómo Firmar con certificado Cliente provisto?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Tengo una aplicación en la que debo enviar data a un servicio web con un certificado de cliente

```vb
        ' datos de conexion 
        DatosVta.idMay = rvconf.PDidMay
        DatosVta.idSubred = rvconf.PDIdSubred
        DatosVta.idPTp = rvconf.PDIdPTP
           '   datos de la venta 
        DatosVta.tidPdv = lote
        DatosVta.tipoProducto = "accion"
        DatosVta.nroLinea = tel
        DatosVta.fechaTransPdv = fechaAhora.ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmss")
        DatosVta.montoTransaccion = monto
```

En principio no debería ser DatosVta lo que debe ir firmado, si no que debes añadir el certificado a tu webService, algo asi como

```vb
ws.ClientCertificates.Add(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(rutaATuCertificado));
```

basandome en lo dicho arriba, me quedaria asi:

```vb
ws.ClientCertificates.Add(X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(rvconf.PDRootCert))
```

Pero aun sigo sin saber como asocio el "datosVta" .... al certificado

Agradezco de antemano

Pablo

Comment: En principio no debería ser `DatosVta` lo que debe ir firmado, si no que debes añadir el certificado a tu webService, algo asi como `ws.ClientCertificates.Add(
        X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(rutaATuCertificado));`

Comment: No sera con un certificado de camerfirma no? Llevo días pegandome con ellos.

Comment: GDP: no es de camerfirma.  es de un proveedor de la empresa donde trabajo.

Comment: Pikoh: gracias por la data. voy a ver si buscando por ese lado lo resuelvo .

Comment: Es que no debes asociar `DatosVta` al certificado. Una vez la conexión del webservice tenga el certificado correcto, el servidor debería admitir el objeto.